# How to copy primary key from master table to child table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

How to copy primary key (Shared Key) from master table to child table in Hibernate. I am trying to do **unidirectional** mapping (`Employee` has reference to `Address` not vice-versa).

Additional Info:
Hibernate dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I have `Employee` class and `Address` entities as given below. I am trying to generated Primary key in `Employee` entity to `Address` entity.

But, I see `employeeId` in `ADDRESS` table is always generated as 0 by hibernate (I was expecting that to be copied). I guess I would be doing wrong while using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` or `@MapsId`. I have tried to add both, or add one among them but no luck.

The following is the schema the corresponding tables:

```
create table EMPLOYEE(
EMPLOYEE_ID int auto_increment,
NAME varchar(100),
SALARY double,
primary key(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);



create table ADDRESS
(
EMPLOYEE_ID int references EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID,
STREET_NAME varchar(40),
CITY_NAME varchar(40),
STATE_NAME varchar(40),
ZIP_CODE varchar(40),
primary key(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
```

The entity mapping looks like below:

Employee.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private double salary;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
   @MapsId
    //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Employee setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public Employee setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
        return this;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Employee setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                ", address=" + address +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Address.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "STREET_NAME")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
    private String cityName;

    @Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
    private String stateName;

    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
    private String zipCode;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Address setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public Address setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public Address setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public Address setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public Address setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", streetName='" + streetName + '\'' +
                ", cityName='" + cityName + '\'' +
                ", stateName='" + stateName + '\'' +
                ", zipCode='" + zipCode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Save method:

```
  public Employee save(Employee employee){

        Session session = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(address); // Should I do this?            
        session.save(employee);
        transaction.commit();
        return employee;
    }
```

Comment: Here is a nice [howto](http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-with-shared-primary-key-annotation-example/) pretty close to your problem

Comment: Yes. if you look at the code while saving entity, the **Student** (in the example) entity is persisted twice in given **example**. one by calling `persist` and other by `save` after updating address.  Do I have to do the same? I was expecting to hibernate to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to model the association on the entity that copies the primary key value. If you do that, you can annotate the association with `@MapsId`.

In your example, the primary key of the `Employee` entity gets generated using the [IDENTITY strategy](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/), and the `Address` entity shall use the same value. To make that work, you need to model the [one-to-one association](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/) on the `Address` entity. You can either use a bidirectional or a unidirectional association mapping.

If you prefer a unidirectional one, you can use the same the mapping annotations as you use on the `address` attribute of your `Employee` entity. You would then, of course, need to remove the `address` attribute afterwards ;)

In a bidirectional mapping, your `Employee` entity would look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private double salary;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Address address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Employee setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public Employee setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
        return this;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Employee setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                ", address=" + address +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And this is the `Address` entity. The important part of this mapping is the `@MapsId` annotation on the one-to-one association.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "STREET_NAME")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
    private String cityName;

    @Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
    private String stateName;

    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
    private String zipCode;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")
    @MapsId
    private Employee employee

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Address setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public Address setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public Address setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public Address setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public Address setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        return this;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee emp) {
        this.employee = emp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", streetName='" + streetName + '\'' +
                ", cityName='" + cityName + '\'' +
                ", stateName='" + stateName + '\'' +
                ", zipCode='" + zipCode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

As you can see, I removed the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation. It is only used if your entity gets mapped to 2 database tables. That can be the case if you use the [inheritance strategy JOINED](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) or if you work with a legacy database and need to [map 2 tables to the same entity](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/).

Comment: Thank you, So, I have to map `Employee` in `Address` entity to make it work. What I thought is Employee has an address but not the other way and hence modelling this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to copy the primary key manually. If you are using an ORM like hibernate, you need to actually pass the entity object ( in your case Address entity object) to the class object(In your case Employee) for which you want to create the 1-1 mapping. Hibernate will automatically, use the entities primary key(addresses primary key) to populate the column (address column in Employee table) in the mapping entity. You can look at this example here which is very similar to your case : 
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Here if you see, they have a primary key for Address table which is addressId. Now in the student class, they have a field of type Address which is marked as @OneToOne which means its a mapping. Now, in student class constructor we are passing the address object. Now, in main function if you see we are only saving the student object ( not the address object). Now when the transaction is saved, hibernate will know, to first create the the address entity because student entity depends on it, and then save the student entity with the primary key of the created address entity.

Now when you, fetch the student entity, hibernate will automatically fetch the Address entity also looking at the addressId in the student table. Hope it helps. Let me know if any more clarifications are need.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it does not match with what am I trying to do. I am trying to explore and understand using of `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and `@MapsId`..

Answer (score 0):

I have mapped the entities like below:

Look at below in code in `Employee.java`

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address address;
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    public Employee(){

    }
    public Employee(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee(String name,double salary){
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private double salary;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Employee setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public Employee setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
        return this;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Employee setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BiEmployee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                ", address=" + address +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "STREET_NAME")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
    private String cityName;

    @Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
    private String stateName;

    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
    private String zipCode;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_CODE")
    private Country country;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Address setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public Address setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public Address setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public Address setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public Address setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        return this;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public Address setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BiAddress{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", streetName='" + streetName + '\'' +
                ", cityName='" + cityName + '\'' +
                ", stateName='" + stateName + '\'' +
                ", zipCode='" + zipCode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Adding Country.java for completeness

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_CODE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int countryCode;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String name;

    public int getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public Country setCountryCode(int countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Country setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```